# WP8 accessing result of Task causes crash when debugger is not attached

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

```
Task<string> t = Helpers.InsertTodoItem(todoItem, imageStream);
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("Inserted"));

t.ContinueWith((i) =>
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("In ContinueWith"));
    try
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(t.Result.ToString()));
    }
    catch (Exception ze)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(ze.ToString()));
    }

    //string r = (string)t.Result.Substring(t.Result.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("Uploaded"));

});
```

The above is a code segment from a WP8 app I am working on

When running with the debugger attached (on an emulator or actual device), it works fine.

When I run it without the debugger, it shows the "In ContinueWith" message and then just shuts down.

Is there a way to pinpoint what the error is and resolve it? The Exception does not pop up either

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out, after showing the messagebox, the execution would move on to the next lines of code where, due to an uninitialized variable, a null reference exception would cause a crash before I saw the messagebox showing the exception

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `t` in the continuation method, use `i`, but they are the same thing. If you suspect that the problem is in accessing the result, why don't you wrap `t.Result` in some `try-catch` block?